# Reading oozie capture-output element using oozie java api

Tags: java, shell, hadoop, cloudera, oozie

I am using the Oozie java client Api to start a shell action from my java program. I want to read the capture output element of the shell action form my java program. I tried using the function below. But, I got a NullPointerException.

```
org.apache.oozie.DagELFunctions.wf_actionData(String actionName)
```

Here is the java program to submit the Oozie job using the Java Client API.

```
public class OozieSample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws OozieClientException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // get a OozieClient for local Oozie
    OozieClient wc = new OozieClient("http://bar:8080/oozie");

    // create a workflow job configuration and set the workflow application path
    Properties conf = wc.createConfiguration();
    conf.setProperty(OozieClient.APP_PATH, "hdfs://foo:9000/usr/tucu/my-wf-app");

    // setting workflow parameters
    conf.setProperty("jobTracker", "foo:9001");

    // submit and start the workflow job
    String jobId = wc.run(conf);
    System.out.println("Workflow job submitted");
    System.out.println(jobId);

    // wait until the workflow job finishes printing the status every 10 seconds
    while (wc.getJobInfo(jobId).getStatus() == WorkflowJob.Status.RUNNING) {
        System.out.println("Workflow job running ...");
        Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
    }

    System.out.println(org.apache.oozie.DagELFunctions.wf_actionData("shell-5ed8"));

    // print the final status o the workflow job
    System.out.println("Workflow job completed ...");

    }
```

Is there a way to read the oozie capture-output element from a java program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell action `capture-output` is written as `Properties` in action `data` field ([SshActionExecutor.java:142](https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/branch-4.1/core/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/action/ssh/SshActionExecutor.java)). This can be accessed via Oozie [REST Api](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/WebServicesAPI.html#Job_Information).

I did some test with curl and it is there:

```
curl http://host:11000/oozie/v1/job/job-id?show=info
```

Response fragment:

```
{
   //(...)
   "actions": [
     {
       //(...)
       "data": "#\n#Tue May 15 15:04:48 EEST 2018\nfoo=bar\n"
     }
   ]
}
```

This was an action with shell script `echo "foo=bar"`.

Since `OozieClient` is a wrapper over this API, something like this should work:

```
WorkflowJob job = oozieClient.getJobInfo("oozie-wf-id");

String data = job.getActions().stream()
        .filter(action -> "shell-5ed8".equals(action.getName()))
        .map(WorkflowAction::getData)
        .findFirst().orElse("");

Properties actionProperties = new Properties();
actionProperties.load(new StringReader(data));
```